# Export scrapy objects into one file per item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get contents of some webpages. Is there a way to configure scrapy so that it exports each dataline into a separate file?

Comment: Do you mean each `item` instance into a separate file?

Comment: @alecxe yes, I mean each item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can yield items in your spider to return multiple items to be processed in your pipeline.

```
class SomeSpider(Spider):

  ...

  def parse(self, response):
    # some code to parse the webpage

    for some_line in webpage:
        item = YourItem()
        # parse items

        yield item
```

This will return multiple items for one scraped page. Then just specify your pipeline to write each item to a separate file.

```
class SomePipeline(object):

  ...      

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:

          # format your item into a line here

          f.write(line)
```